# Span of permutation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, permutation-matrices

The set $P$ of $n \times n$ permutation matrices spans a subspace of dimension $(n-1)^2+1$ within, say, the $n \times n$ complex matrices.  Is there another description of this space?  In particular, I am interested in a description of a subset of the permutation matrices which will form a basis.

For $n=1$ and $2$, this is completely trivial -- the set of all permutation matrices is linearly independent.  For $n=3$, the dimension of their span is $5$, and any five of the six permutation matrices are linearly independent, as can be seen from the following dependence relation:

$$ \sum_{M \in P} \det (M) \ M = 0 $$

So even in the case $n=4$, is there a natural description of a $10$ matrix basis?

Comment: In Louck's book [Applications of Unitary Symmetry and Combinatorics](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/8161#t=aboutBook) there is a whole chapter 2 on linear relations and construction of various bases in the span of permutation matrices.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As user1551 points out, your space is the span of all "magic matrices" -- all $n\times n$ matrices for which every row and column sum is equal to the same constant (depending on the matrix).  As an algebra this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C} \oplus M_{n-1}(\mathbb{C})$.

You can think of this as the image in $\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ of the natural representation of $S_n$ on $n$ points -- perhaps this is where your question comes from.  The representation decomposes as the direct sum of the trivial rep and an $(n-1)$-dimensional irreducible.

The set of permutation matrices coming from the permutations $1$, $(1,r)$, $(1,r,s)$ for $1\neq r \neq s \neq 1$ form a basis of this space.  To see that they are linearly independent, consider the first rows then the first columns of the corresponding matrices.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the nice basis.

Comment: Why the basis is linearly independent? I don't see it by considering the first row and first column.

Comment: When you speak of $M_{n-1}(\mathbb{C})$ are you speaking of the list of all matrices under the Lie bracket? Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

The Birkhoff–von Neumann theorem states that the convex hull of permutation matrices is the set of all [doubly stochastic matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix). Hence the span of all permutation matrices is given by $S=\{X\in M_{n,n}(\mathbb{C}): \textrm{ all column sums and row sums of } X \textrm{ are equal}\}$.

Answer (score 2):

The set of permutation matrices indexed by the permutations having an increasing subsequence of length $n-1$ is a basis. This set is the same as the set of *consecutive* cycles, that is, permutations of $n$ that consecutively cycle a set of consecutive numbers. For example, $3 \mapsto 4 \mapsto 5 \mapsto 3$ is a consecutive cycle (as is its inverse) but $3 \mapsto 5 \mapsto 6 \mapsto 3$ is not.

This result is proved, and vastly generalized, in  https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.00107.