# rank for the matrix of concatenating all $N \times N$ permutation matrics

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider all $N\times N$ permutation matrix $\{M_1,M_2,\ldots,M_{N!}\}$

Define $S_N$ as concatenating each $\operatorname{vec}(M_i)$ as $S_N$'s $i$th column

Is there any convenient way to calculate $\operatorname{rank}(S_N)$ ?

Take $N=3$ for example.

$$M_1=\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right]$$
$$M_2=\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right]$$
$$M_3=\left[\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right]$$
...

then
$$S_3=\left[\begin{matrix}
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1  \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1  \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

and $\operatorname{rank}(S_3)=5$

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

In general this should be 1 plus the dimension $(n-1)^2$ of the [Birkhoff polytope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff_polytope).  The extra $1$ just comes from it lying in an affine, rather than linear, subspace.

Comment: Thanks, I found a similar problem, which might be more general(in some aspects) [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70569/span-of-permutation-matrices). mt_ even gives the $(1+(n-1)^2)$ basis for this space.